# comparing two lists to choose maximum

Tags: python, list

I have two lists l1 and l2:

```
l1 = [x,y,3,4,5]
l2 = [x,y,30,1,2]
```

I want to make a list l3 which is the list that has the maximum in the 3rd element of the list (in the above example it would be 3 in l1 and 30 in l2). In the above case 
    l3 = [x,y,30,1,2]
How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `key` argument of `max` to get the list with the larger element `[2]`

```
l3 = max((l1, l2), key = lambda i: i[2])
```

Comment: That's what the `key` argument does - it defines how to compare the two input lists. Though it's a good habit to get used to using `operator.itemgetter(2)` for such key functions - it won't matter at all here, but over sufficiently large data sets it outperforms a lambda.

Comment: Oh, and there's no need to make a tuple - `max(l1, l2, key=operator.itemgetter(2))` works fine too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple `if/else` considering you are just comparing two elements:

```
l3 = l1 if l1[2] > l2[2] else l2
```

But beware you are creating a *reference* not a copy.

If you want a new list you need to copy:

```
l3 = l1[:] if l1[2] > l2[2] else l2[:]
```

If you don't copy any changes to in this case `l2` as it has the larger third element will be reflected in l3 and vice-versa.

Also if you have other mutable objects in the list you will need to make a `copy.deepcopy`:

```
from copy import deepcopy
l3 = deepcopy(l1 ) if l1[2] > l2[2] else deepcopy(l2)
```

Comment: All good points re: what's a copy vs. what's another reference, independent of the other answer's examination of how to choose the semantically "larger" list.